# How to parse user mentions in PHP

Tags: php

I am developing a system where user enters his message in following format:

Hey @john are you coming in birthday party of @elise?

here as soon as you type @ in text box dropdown appears and you can select desired name from that.

My problem is is while posting the message it should be HTML code like this.

```
Hey <a href="http://www.mysite.com/user/id/123">John Doe</a> are you coming in
birthday party of <a href="http://www.mysite.com/user/id/789">Elise Lisa</a>?

preg_replace("/@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)(?=\?|\,|\;|\.|\s|\Z)/", <new_html>, <old_string>);
```

So how do I find all the occurrences of @ in string and process them?? Since I need to pass a function call getUserName($shortname) and getUserID($shortname) where $shortname is text after @. Also I need to call the function NotifyUser() for every call of the respective shortname.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a problem to me. Why do you have a problem with it?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to run through the string, identify all words starting with '@' and then run your function on these:

```
$text = 'say hello to @elise and @john';

function replace_at_symbol($matches){
    return "(here you would replace: ".$matches[0]." with something)";
}

$output = preg_replace_callback("/([@][a-zA-Z-0-9]+)/", "replace_at_symbol", $text);
echo $output;
```